# Are quantum RNGs on an Android device possible?

Tags: hardware

I edited out the term *quantum* in [this question on SoftwareRecs.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/70365/rng-software-for-android-phones) on the assumption that actual quantum effects on an Android device cannot be measured/harvested from - things like radioactive decay, photon counting, laser phase noise, zener noise (more options mentioned e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03304.pdf)).

But maybe I'm wrong: are random number generators using quantum effects in Android devices possible (and available)?

(I'm not asking for software recommendations, that should be on the other question).

Comment: Err, I'm not sure where to start since I lack the knowledge on quantum. However, as you might have known, Android has [many types of sensors](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview) which can be accessed by 3rd-party apps, so RNG based on their output is possible (can't speak on the "entropy"-thing). Looking from the list, I don't think those are considered quantum phenomena...

Comment: However, Android OS itself is open-source and very customizable, and there are Android devices for specialized purpose (e.g. TV, Watch, [IoT](https://developer.android.com/things)). So, if there are external devices that can detect quantum phenomena and has communication channels like Bluetooth or WiFi, then I *think* Android device can use that, potentially needs some modifications though.

Comment: @AndrewT. That's exactly the distinction I want to make, noise should be based on quantum effects. And [there are indeed quantum devices](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+quantum+rng)

Comment: There is a very good RNG source on nearly every Android device available: the CMOS camera sensor, or in detail the noise of the captured images. It can even be used to measure nuclear radiation (there are scientific papers on that topic available).